# Is there a map for the Death March's world?

Tags: death-march

I tried looking for it online, but it got drowned in tons of scanlated pages, several SS of the anime, and a [kumo-desu-ga-nani-ga](/questions/tagged/kumo-desu-ga-nani-ga) map.

Is there a map of the Death March's world?

Comment: [Some fans on 2chan created it in Japanese](https://www65.atwiki.jp/death-march/pages/140.html). Feel free for anyone to use it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Aki Tanaka commented, here are the best looking fan-made maps:
[image]
Auyugok territory map
[image]
Good luck understanding it :p